# Proper User for Ubuntu Nginx PHP-FPM when running php bin/magento and composer Command Line

Tags: magento2, nginx, cli, php-fpm

So on the setup mentioned in the title, I want to confirm how the user should be for command line. Using the default setup there is a user "nginx" that is used for php-fpm and for nginx.

Should that user "nginx" be used for composer install and updates, as well as php bin/magento commands? So I would log into SSH as that user?

I tried making all the files/folders owned by nginx:nginx and creating another user and putting them in the same group as "nginx", logging in as that new user and then running the php bin/magento commands like clear cache but it gives errors like cache is not writable (even though it is for nginx user).

I have already reviewed the docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html but this is still not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple:

- **nginx** - only `read` files
- **php-fpm** - `read` and `write` files

you have files access as **`user:group:other`**

`chmod` for folders `2770` for files `660`

**`:other`** dont have to access your files at all.

usually nginx and php-fpm have different user names.

so you need to change your permissions to allow **nginx** `read` and **php-fpm** `read` `write`.

if you add new user, it will be in **`:group:`**
make sure group have **`write`** access also.

*...*

*p.s.*
but better do not change anything, do not mess with user groups and do not move anyone to any group, just change access right with ACL settings, easy to add/remove users with more precise config:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/setfacl.1.html